# how to Convert to VB.NET code in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

Please convert this code to VB.NET.

```
var catcopy2 = categories.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new CategoriesBackup() {
    CategoryID = x.CategoryID,
    CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
    Description = x.Description,
    Picture = x.Picture
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just using Reflector or a similar decompiler? Which part of it is causing you difficulties?

Comment: accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

check this tool : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Dim catcopy2 = categories.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New CategoriesBackup() With { _
    Key .CategoryID = x.CategoryID, _
    Key .CategoryName = x.CategoryName, _
    Key .Description = x.Description, _
    Key .Picture = x.Picture _
})
```

Comment: Why does VB have to uglify everything?